# Symfony Doctrine - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql, symfony-3.4

I wrote some complex api to return results from stdClass objects in my controller.
That part works fine.

Then, in my service I wrote a query builder that needs to restrict  results to 6 months period.
That works too when dump().

Problem arises when I try to pull my results through function within query builder.
It throws:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

My Controller:

```
    $getResults = $this->getAllNames()->getContent();
    $pullResults = json_decode($getResults);
    $results = $pullResults->data->items;

    // restricted to 6 month period
    $this->get('my.service')->getDateRange($results); --->this part throws error

    $rows = [];

    $rows[] = array(
        "First Name",
        "Last Name"
    );

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $rows[] = array(
            $row->firstName,
            $row->lastName
        );
    }
```

My Service:

```
 public function getDateRange($results)
{
    return $this->getNamesRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.created >= :end')
        ->andWhere('t.id >= :id')
        ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime('-6 month'))
        ->setParameter('id', $results)
        ->orderBy('t.id', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your $results variable is array than it could not work like above, 
It would like below,

```
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('id', $results));
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. I tried the solution and it throws: Call to a member function add() on array. @Kiran